# How to query fields and count in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Is it possible to write the following SQL in Ecto3?
As I'd like to write a pagination logic at last, the inner count SQL should return the count to match the condition in the inner SQL not the condition in the outer one.

> SELECT id, (SELECT count(*) FROM questions WHERE id>10) AS count FROM questions WHERE id > 10 LIMIT 3 OFFSET1;

Update: DB is mysql

Comment: I found this link hope it's useful. https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html#content

Comment: Are you sure your sql is good enough? it returns all ids and count not for id, but one result like ("id1",10);("id2",10);("id3",10) - I mean 10 is value all all rows, because it will select  count(*) FROM questions WHERE id>10 for all id. Maybe you need group by?

Answer (score 0):

I could satisfy my requirement with `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`. As a summarize, I've published a module which dealt with `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`

- https://github.com/hykw/tiny_ecto_helper_mysql